# Can we Make Graphs To display the data in graphics in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Can we Make Graphs To display the data in graphics in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

[If you're using .Net 4 there are charting controls are built-in now](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx).

[If you're on 3.5, there's an older version available](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx).

These are the 2 built-in and free options already available...whether they fit your needs if for you to decide :)

If you're older than 3.5 you'll have to go with [a third party solution](http://www.asp.net/(S(dfjoah55n4ywsy45zregske4))/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=7) (there are more, but those are most of the big ones).

Comment: any link of third party control

Comment: @user341155 - There's a good list maintained on the asp.net site here: http://www.asp.net/(S(dfjoah55n4ywsy45zregske4))/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=7

Comment: http://www.codecapers.com/post/Build-a-Dashboard-With-Microsoft-Chart-Controls.aspx

This is one of the best examples of how to use the MS Chart control in MVC i have come across

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page from a [famous `asp.net` site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341155?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) (actually, asp.net MVC) - it contains charted reputation data.
The graphics are rendered on the browser with the help of [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) - a pure Javascript plotting library for jQuery. On the `asp.net` server side, the application provides data in `JSON` format.